# Does apex record merge do the same as Lightning Duplicate Merge?

Tags: apex, merge

We need to customize the behavior of the Lightning Merge wizard. But, as far as I understand, this wizard is not customizable. So we are going to create a custom Lightning component with a similar interface but with some additional business logic on a background.

**Question**: Does Lightning Merge functionality works the same way as Apex merge?

```
merge masterContact duplicateContact;
```